# Aptana3 incompatible with firefox7? How to let A3 debugger works?

Tags: firefox, aptana, aptana3

error notice: http://www.picdepict.com/images/46562272935419840850.png

Aptana3 - debug as... js app, then install Aptana Debugger into firefox7. pops up the Error notice

In firefox, notice that Aptana Debugger incompatible with firefox7.0.1
aptana debugger service require firebug 1.2-1.7.

I installed firebug 1.8.3...

Em...Which firefox version is supported, how to let A3 debugger works...

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue: http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-3173.